# How to send request from jsp to controller in Spring 4?

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

I'm using Spring 4. and Hibernate 5

I want know how to pass request from jsp page to controller.

I have like page like below.

I am getting this error:

> *message /Spring_Hibernate_MVC/forgotPsw.do
>
> description The requested resource is not available.*

**ForgotPassword.js**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Forgot Password</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="DivForgotPsw">
        <form action="forgotPsw.do" method="get">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Enter your email id.</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Send"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**ForgotPswController.java**

```
@Component
@RequestMapping(name="/")
public class ForgotPswController {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;



    public ForgotPswController() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName()+" created...");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/forgotPsw.do" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void send( HttpServletRequest request){

        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper;

        try {
            helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
            helper.setSubject("Reset Your Jspiders Account.");
            helper.setTo(request.getParameter("email"));
            helper.setText("Hello User", true);   

            javaMailSender.send(message);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {


            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first get the full request to check it.

```
String req = request.getQueryString();
```

In this request the parameters might be saved with some namespaces. Then you should know the reason.

Using

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<form:from ... modelAttribute=forgotPsw>
<form:input path="email"/>
...
```

might be easier to convert form to Object and to get some info.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/forgotPsw.do" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void send(@ModelAttribute("forgotPsw")ForgotPsw forgotPsw){

class ForgotPsw {

    private String email;
    //getter and setter
}
```

Comment: my request it's not coming on Controller,
i think that is problem...??? how to solve.

if the request its not coming how i check 
request.getQueryString();

Comment: So if I understand you ForgotPassword.js is form another app. In this case if I were you I would try to debug the request params by this function getQueryString then you should see if the param mail exists. It should be sth like this "email=test@test.com". If you do not have it, it means that sth might be wrong with this request.